# Node.js Parsing A Number Inside a String

Tags: regex, node.js, serverside-javascript

Given a string like:

```
Recipient: test@test.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0 (permanent failure)
Diagnostic: No
```

How do I get the "5.0.0" and "permanent failure" only if it's always after Status: ? ?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
var regex = /Status: ([0-9\.]+) \(([a-zA-Z ]+)\)/
var result = string.match(regex);
var statusNumber = result[1];
var statusString = result[2];
```

You should extend these: [0-9\.], [a-zA-Z ] selectors if you expect other characters in these values. For now the first one expects numbers and dots, the second characters and spaces

Comment: Why is this one regEx returning 2 results?

Comment: Alsoe ^ and $ should not be there

Comment: @haemse It's returning two results because there are two capturing groups in it. Actually it's returning three, the first one (at index 0) being the full match. The ^ and $ wasn't in the original answer. I removed them. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorrry seems like str.match(reg) returns an array of all matches whereas reg.exec returns an array with details for one result. Also all the matching groups.